# Do I need to buy Call of Cthulhu 7th edition if I have the quickstart and previous editions?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu, edition-comparison

I've just picked up the quickstart for Call of Cthulhu 7th edition, which I thought was great. Given that it seems to cover off most of the essential game crunch (conflict resolution, and character generation primarily), I'm wondering if I actually need to buy the full version.

I have a bunch of 5th ed books including the core book, so I'm covered for lore and adventures, and conversion doesn't seem difficult. Given that my coffers are running a little light and the new edition is kind of pricey even as a pdf, can I get away without purchasing it? Are there any essential rules that I can't get by combining the quickstart with previous editions?

Comment: How could any answer not be opinion?

Comment: @Ruut Because I'm asking what essential rules I'm missing? That's at least semi objective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes you can get away without purchasing it.**

Covered by Quickstart rules:

- Character creation
- Skill checks
- Basic Sanity mechanics
- Basic Combat mechanics
- Basic Damage & healing mechanics

Covered by 5th edition core book

- Skill descriptions
- Full Sanity mechanics (regaining sanity through therapy, ...)
- More Combat factors, such as cover and lightning (moon light, etc...)
- More damage & health factors
- Entities (monsters, old ones, ...) can be taken from any book which has descriptions (assuming you use stats for them)
- Reading of Mythos tomes & lore
- Spells descriptions & casting

I can't think of an essential rule that you're missing by combining both editions.